# Need to write a test for a gui app

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, gui-testing

I am looking to automate control clicks, listview clicks and so forth, is there any good framework for qt that can help? I need to perform these tests without the source code

Comment: Qt comes with its own testing module. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QtTest.html  I don't understand what automate means. You still have to specify the behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

Qt provides its own framework for unit testing: QTestLib

This library is part of every Qt SDK.

You can find a tutorial [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial.html), Especially the points 3 and 4 will show a way that might be sufficient for your GUI testing needs.

Obviously, starting from point 1 won't hurt.

Comment: The problem is i dont have source code for this app, which makes this option not option right?

Comment: Yeah you would need the source code. I assumed you were going to test your own software.

Answer (score 1):

For a full-blown UI testing framework, have a look at [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/). It supports scripting of UI interactions (with Python, tcl, javascript), property and screenshots comparisons. It requires you to purchase license(s), but it's well worth the money if you do commercial software development.